# RecyclerView - how to use?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a weather application and I use recyclerview to show the weather information. The app runs successfully but has some error and my layout gets displayed in this manner while running in AVD and Android devices.

[image: Layout in AVD and devices]

But in preview in Android studio its gets displayed as in the image below

[image: Layout in preview]

and the code i used of the layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/touch_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_item_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_item_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_padding_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:src="@drawable/art_clouds"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_date_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/list_item_date_start_margin"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/weather_icon"
        tools:text="Today, April 03"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="Rainy"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/high_temperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/forecast_temperature_space"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/forecast_temperature_space"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/forecast_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/low_temperature"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="19\u00b0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/low_temperature"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/forecast_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="10\u00b0"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What might be the error?
The code for onCreateViewholder is as follows:

```
 @Override
    public ForecastAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        int layoutId;

        switch (viewType) {

            case VIEW_TYPE_TODAY: {
                layoutId = R.layout.list_item_forecast_today;
                break;
            }

            case VIEW_TYPE_FUTURE_DAY: {
                layoutId = R.layout.forecast_list_item;
                break;
            }

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type, value of " + viewType);
        }

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutId, viewGroup, false);

        view.setFocusable(true);

        return new ForecastAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code for `onCreateViewHolder()` in your adapter. I think I know what the problem is, but I need to see that code first.

Comment: Can you review the question again. I have added the code for onCreateViewHolder().

Comment: The thing I expected to see in your adapter code isn't there, so the problem must be elsewhere. Could you please post the XML code for the layout that includes your `<RecyclerView>`?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below code it may be helpful:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        tools:text="Today, April 03"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        tools:text="Rainy"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/high_temperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        tools:text="19\u00b0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/low_temperature"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:text="10\u00b0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***Show below screen short :***

[image]

Comment: i used the xml code you provided.But, still i face similar problem.